# How to solve this PDE for steady state?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

```
F1[x1_, x2_] := (a1 x1^n)/(s^n + x1^n)  + (b1 s^n)/(s^n + x2^n) - 
   k1 x1 ;

F2[x1_, x2_] := (a2 x2^n)/(s^n + x2^n)  + (b2 s^n)/(s^n + x1^n) - 
   k2 x2 ;

a1 = a2 = a = 1; b1 = b2 = b = 1; k1 = k2 = 1; s = 0.5;
dd = 0.1; n = 4;

DSolve[-D[F1[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x1] - D[F2[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x2] + D[dd*P[x1, x2], x1,x1]+ D[dd*P[x1, x2], x2,x2] == 0, P[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
```

I am trying to solve the above equation. However, Mathematica does not give me anything. The reason for this must be because there is no analytical solution for this problem. So, it would make sense to get a numerical solution for it. For that specifying initial conditions, would be useful but I couldn't find that in the paper (link below).

I am trying to get figures like Fig 2 B, Fig 3, and Fig 5 from the paper below:
https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/108/20/8257.full.pdf

Addendum:

Using `U[x1, x2] = -Log[P[x1,x2]]`

I can try to solve directly for `U[x1,x2]`:

```
   NDSolve[-D[F1[x1, x2]*Exp[-U[x1, x2]], x1] - 
   D[F2[x1, x2]*Exp[-U[x1, x2]], x2] + 
   D[dd*Exp[-U[x1, x2]], x1, x1] + D[dd*Exp[-U[x1, x2]], x2, x2] == 
   0, U, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}]
```

But again, I need boundary conditions to do so.

[image]

Based on the figure above, now I have a problem that looks like this:
[image]

Mathematica still can't solve it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ psimeson What's P[x,y] !?

Comment: Joint Probability of x and y.

Comment: dose it have a definition !?

Comment: i mean you need to state its definition or math equations or Mathematica equation

Comment: Usually, $P[x1,x2,t]$ is time depedent and for long time limit $P[x1,x2,t ->\infty]$ we get $P^{ss}$, which is the steady state distribution. The time-dependance drops out for this case.

Comment: i spotted some coding mistakes but still needing please the original math problem. edit your question plz and include the math problem it self

Comment: I am sorry but I am do not understand what you mean here. The math problem is to solve the problem that the bottom of the post above. I am just trying to go through this paper https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/108/20/8257.full.pdf and figure out a way to get figure 3 A, which  boils down to solving a steady-state Fokker-Planck in 2D.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124979/discussion-between-psimeson-and-alrubaie).

Comment: This reminds me of some work by [Nolting & Abbott](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1890/15-1047.1) and [Moore et al.](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2016/RJ-2016-031/index.html).  The first even has a Mathematica notebook, but unfortunately it calls some R code for the heavy parts (?!).  I wish I understood stochastic modeling better!

Comment: One idea: instead of going straight to the steady state, can you numerically solve a time-dependent version?

Comment: @ChrisK I didn't try that. I thought a steady-state would be easier to solve than a time-dependent version.

Comment: @psimeson Give it a try, it might help.  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279577/when-the-false-transient-method-could-make-an-elliptic-pde-easier-to-solve-numer

Comment: Now that the obstacle doesn't lie in programming side, have you tried contacting the authors of the paper?

Comment: I wrote to the authors a few days back but I haven't heard from them.

Answer (score 8):

Following @user21's suggestion to look at [this example in the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1981924737), I made the following tweaks:

```
vars = {p[t, x1, x2], t, {x1, x2}};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 3}];
pars = <|"ModelForm" -> "Conservative", 
   "DiffusionCoefficient" -> {{d, 0}, {0, d}}, 
   "MassConvectionVelocity" -> {F1[x1, x2], F2[x1, x2]}, d -> 1/10|>;
ics = p[0, x1, x2] == PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{1.5, 1.5}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}], {x1, x2}];
eqn = {MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0, ics};

pfun = NDSolveValue[eqn,
  p, {t, 0, 100}, {x1, x2} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 1}}}}}];

DensityPlot[pfun[100, x1, x2], {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Seems to work -- and fast too!

Comment: Actually to get something like this we don't need to introduce `t`: `tst = NDSolveValue[{-D[F1[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x1] - D[F2[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x2] + D[dd*P[x1, x2], x1, x1] + D[dd*P[x1, x2], x2, x2] == 0, P[x1, 3] == -10^-3, P[3, x2] == -10^-3}, P, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}]; DensityPlot[tst[x1, x2], {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50]` Still, the figure is not the same as the given one, but of course, the ambiguous paper is blameworthy.

Comment: @xzczd I should get figure 3B with this `Plot3D[-Log[tst[x1, x2]], {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]` but it gives something different.

Comment: @xzczd That's great, you should add that as an answer!  As for the differences with the paper, it does seem unclear in a lot of aspects.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChrisK. This way I get the time evolution of the distribution itself.

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution as illustration to Figure 3 from the paper  Quantifying the Waddington landscape and biological paths for development and differentiation by Jin Wang, Kun Zhang, Li Xu, and Erkang Wang.

```
n = 4; s = S = 1/2; k1 = k2 = 1; b1 = b2 = 1; a1 = a2 = 1; dd = 1/10;

F1[x1_, x2_] := (a1 x1^n)/(s^n + x1^n) + (b1 s^n)/(s^n + x2^n) - k1 x1;

F2[x1_, x2_] := (a2 x2^n)/(s^n + x2^n) + (b2 s^n)/(s^n + x1^n) - k2 x2;

tst = NDSolveValue[{-D[F1[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x1] - 
      D[F2[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x2] + D[dd*P[x1, x2], x1, x1] + 
      D[dd*P[x1, x2], x2, x2] == 0, P[x1, 3] == Exp[-10 Exp[x1/3]], 
    P[3, x2] == Exp[-10 Exp[x2/3]]}, P, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}];
```

For visualization we can use vector field `{F1,F2}` and $\nabla U$ as well. In Figure 3 these fields combined in one picture, but we show its as follows

```
Show[DensityPlot[-Log[tst[x1, x2]^2 + 10^-10]/2, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 
   3}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotPoints -> 50], 
 VectorPlot[{F1[x1, x2], F2[x1, x2]}, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}, 
  VectorPoints -> Fine, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorStyle -> White]]

Show[DensityPlot[-Log[tst[x1, x2]^2 + 10^-10]/2, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 
   3}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotPoints -> 50], 
 VectorPlot[
  Evaluate[{D[tst[x1, x2], x1], D[tst[x1, x2], x2]}/tst[x1, x2]], {x1,
    0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}, VectorPoints -> Fine, 
  VectorColorFunction -> None, VectorStyle -> Yellow]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. We can reproduce some part of the Waddington developmental landscape with the model above as follows

```
n = 4; s = S = 1/2; k1 = k2 = 1; b1 = b2 = 1; dd = 1/10;

F1[x1_, x2_] := (a x1^n)/(s^n + x1^n) + (b1 s^n)/(s^n + x2^n) - k1 x1;

F2[x1_, x2_] := (a x2^n)/(s^n + x2^n) + (b2 s^n)/(s^n + x1^n) - k2 x2;

tst = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-D[F1[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x1] - 
      D[F2[x1, x2]*P[x1, x2], x2] + D[dd*P[x1, x2], x1, x1] + 
      D[dd*P[x1, x2], x2, x2] == 0, P[x1, 3] == Exp[-10 Exp[x1/3]], 
    P[3, x2] == Exp[-10 Exp[x2/3]]}, P, {x1, -3, 3}, {x2, -3, 3}, {a}];

lst = Table[{x, 
    a, -Log[tst[a][x, -x]^2]/2 + 15}, {x, -.75, .75, .025}, {a, 
    0.1, .5, .01}];

ListPlot3D[Flatten[lst, 1], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "a", "U"}, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 2. For a>0.5 the landscape can be reproduce with time dependent model only, since in the paper they used equation $\dot{a}=−λa$ with $λ=0.01$.In this case the Fokker-Plank equation can be written as

```
n = 4; s = S = 1/2; k1 = k2 = 1; b1 = 1; b2 = 1; dd = 1/10;

F1[x1_, a_] := (a x1^n)/(s^n + x1^n) - k1 x1 + (b2 s^n)/(s^n + x1^n);



tst = NDSolveValue[{-D[F1[x1, a]*P[x1, a], x1] + 
      0.01 D[a*P[x1, a], a] + D[dd*P[x1, a], x1, x1] + 
      D[dd*P[x1, a], a, a] == 0, 
    P[x1, 1] == Exp[-9.7 - 1.2 Sin[3 x1/2]^2 Exp[Abs[x1/2]] ], 
    P[x1, 0.1] == Exp[-9.7 + 1.2 Sin[2 x1]^2 Exp[Abs[x1]]]}, 
   P, {x1, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {a, .1, 1}];
```

[image: Figure 3]

Update 3. For `a>1` the landscape can be reproduce with time dependent model with using equation $\dot{a}=−a$ ($λ=1$).In this case the Fokker-Plank equation can be written as

```
n = 4; s = S = 1/2; k1 = k2 = 1; b1 = 1; b2 = 1/2; dd = 1/10;

F1[x1_, a_] := (a x1^n)/(s^n + x1^n) - k1 x1 + (b2 s^n)/(s^n + x1^n);



tst = NDSolveValue[{-D[F1[x1, a]*P[x1, a], x1] + D[a*P[x1, a], a] + 
      D[dd*P[x1, a], x1, x1] + D[dd*P[x1, a], a, a] == 0, 
    P[x1, 1.5] == Exp[-9.7 - 1.2 Sin[3 x1/2]^2 Exp[Abs[x1/2]] ], 
    P[x1, 0.1] == Exp[-9.7 + 1.2 Sin[2 x1]^2 Exp[Abs[x1]]]}, 
   P, {x1, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {a, .1, 1.5}];
```

Visualization

```
Plot3D[-Log[Abs[tst[x1, a]]], {x1, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {a, .1, 1.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "a", "U"}, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: So that's what those arrows are!  BTW I think you've got a `F1[x1, x1]` in your first `VectorPlot` that should be `F1[x1, x2]`.

Comment: @ChrisK Thank you very much. It has been update.

Comment: Thanks @AlexTrounev ! Why are you taking the square of `tst[x1,x2]` , adding `10^-10`, and also dividing by `2`? If I stack these to figures then I should get Fig 3,right? Also, do you have any insight about figure 5?

Comment: @ChrisK This is not the end, I'm afraid. There seem to be some vectors along the line `(y - 1.5)/(1.5 - 3) == (x - 3)/(3 - 1.5)` in the original Fig. 3. We haven't yet been able to reproduce these.

Comment: @psimeson We can reproduce some part of the Waddington developmental landscape with the model above. See update to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks again. I was mostly trying to solve for different values of a by trying to make a table, which 
 you did my using `Parametric NDSolveValue`Why are you using `-Log[tst[a][x, -x]^2]/2 + 15` instead of `-Log[tst[a][x, -x]]`? Is it just to make `U` positive? Using what they have I get `U` to be negative.

Comment: @psimeson Potential `U` is defined up to arbitrary constant, so we can add 15 just to compare with Figure 5. Also `Log[ tst[a][x,-x]^2]/2`  equals to `Log[Abs[tst[a][x,-x]]]`. In the paper they are not mentioned that they used $U=-\log{|P|}$ since it is trivia for the real numbers, but it is not true for `Log[]` defined in Mathematica for complex numbers only.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I tried to get the landscape for a= 0.1 to 1.5 but I couldn't get what they have in the paper. I tried with different discretization but with no success.

Comment: @psimeson Yes, you are right, for `a>0.5` the landscape can be reproduce with time dependent model only, since in the paper they used equation $\dot{a}=-\lambda a$ with $\lambda =0.01$. See Update 2 to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev How did you get the boundary conditions?

Comment: @psimeson These boundary conditions have been derived from Figure 5 analysis.

Comment: @AlexTrounev ok. I tried to extend your code to replicate the minima at `a=1.5`. This formalism has to capture that minimum for the landscape to be a differentiation landscape. That's why I was interested in how you came to the boundary conditions.

Comment: @AlexTrounev were you able to get the minima at `a=1.5`? I followed your approach but I wasn't able to get the minima at `a=1.5`. Also the asymmetry on the minima region for at lower values of a not the same as in the paper.

Comment: @psimeson In the paper they just made some illustration, and not what we did here.  In the case `a>1` we can use $\lambda=1$ as it explained in the Supporting Information. See update to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev the problem with $\lambda = 1$ is that you get a biased landscape. A ball from `a=1.5` is always going to roll towards minima at `x=1.0`. This not what we want. Also, I didn't find  $\lambda = 1$  in the SI. This paper (https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0049271) seem to reproduce the result.

Comment: @psimeson It depends on `b2`. For `b2=1/2` we have symmetrical landscape - see update .

Answer (score 7):

Not a complete answer. I haven't looked into the paper and it's not immediately clear to me how the authors obtain those figures, but are you sure they are obtained by solving boundary value problem (BVP) of the PDE? For example, the figure in your question i.e. **Fig 3** just looks like a `VectorDensityPlot` of $(F_1(x_1,\ x_2),\ F_2(x_1,\ x_2))$:

```
VectorDensityPlot[{F1[x1, x2], F2[x1, x2]}, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not exactly the same, but perhaps the parameters are different. (The parameters you chose are for Fig 2. )

As to PDE solving, it's easy to get something similar to that given in Chris K's answer without introducing `t`:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{With[{P = P[x1, x2]}, -D[F1[x1, x2] P, x1] - D[F2[x1, x2] P, x2] + 
      D[dd P, x1, x1] + D[dd P, x2, x2] == 0], P[x1, 3] == -10^-3, P[3, x2] == -10^-3}, 
      P, {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}]; 
DensityPlot[sol[x1, x2], {x1, 0, 3}, {x2, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As we can see, it's still not exactly the same as the one in the paper.

As to the white curve, I've found something related, too. In the [**Supporting Information**](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2011/04/27/1017017108.DCSupplemental/pnas.1017017108_SI.pdf?targetid=STXT) we can find the following system:

[image]

[image]

Solving it yields:

```
With[{x1 = x1[t], x2 = x2[t]}, 
  With[{F1 = F1[x1, x2], F2 = F2[x1, x2]}, 
   V = 1/(4 dd) (F1^2 + F2^2) + 1/2 Div[{F1, F2}, {x1, x2}];
   curl = Curl[{F1, F2}, {x1, x2}];
   neweq = {D[x1, t, t] == 2 dd D[V, x1] + D[x2, t] (-curl), 
     D[x2, t, t] == 2 dd D[V, x2] + D[x1, t] (curl)}]];

shoot[ic_]:={"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions"->ic}

nsolfunc[tend_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{neweq, x1[0] == 2, x2[0] == 0, x1[tend] == 0, x2[tend] == 2}, 
   {x1@t, x2@t}, {t, 0, tend}, 
  Method -> shoot@{x1[0] == 2, x2[0] == 0, x1'[0] == -1, x2'[0] == 3}]

i = 1; 
Show@
  Table[ParametricPlot[nsolfunc[tend] // Evaluate, {t, 0, tend}, 
    Exclusions -> {1/4, 3/4} tend], {tend, {-2, 1/2, 2}}] /. 
   RGBColor[__] :> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i++]] /. {first___, Line@a_, Line@b_, 
    Line@c_, last___} :> {first, Arrow@a, Arrow@b, Line@c, last} // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Once again, it's not exactly the same as in Fig 3. Might get closer if we adjust the initial guess of `"Shooting"` method more carefullly.

Comment: The paper doesn't clearly describe how they get those figures. Even Fig 3a isn't clearly labeled (blue and white arrows). The paper is focused on the construction of landscape from steady-state distribution, which  we can get by solving Fokker Planck (eq 4 https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0049271). So, I was trying to solve FPE.

Comment: @psimeson This paper isn't that clear either, and still, I doubt if solving the PDE is the right way to go. Anyway, this isn't our first question about Fokker Planck equation, have you checked the previous posts?

Comment: I looked at it but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @psimeson Not sure if this is useful, but there is a new example about the [Fokker-Plank equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1981924737)

Comment: Thanks @xzczd for all your insights and codes.